# How to add Class and Remove Class on anchor Click

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am Implementing theme which is the user can select a theme with a click so when I click on setting icon it's run perfectly it's opening but when I click on it again is not closing with jQuery 3.4.1.

Here is my jquery3.4.1 code

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
  $(".theme-button").click(function(){
   $(".theme-colors").addClass("shown");
   $(this).removeClass("shown");
  });
});
```

and i want also in javascript

Here is CDN which is I'm using

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

My expectation is again clicked to close means open and close

jsfiddle [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/368kpu1g/2/)

Comment: I've been having lots of problems with jQuery 3.4.1 in jsfiddle. Going back to 3.3.1 usually fixes them.

Comment: @barmar for fix this issue i need to use 3.3.1 ??

Comment: Instead of using click function to add class, why don't you use toggle() instead?

Comment: In this case I didn't see any difference with the two versions. But where in your code is it supposed to close when you click a second time?

Comment: This works on jQuery edge and 3.4.1 `$(function() {
  $(".theme-button").on("click",function() {
    $(".theme-colors").toggleClass("shown");
  });
});
`

Comment: i want in javascript

Answer (score 2):

Use `toggleClass()`

```
$(".theme-colors").toggleClass("shown");
```

[Updated fiddle link.](https://jsfiddle.net/vd7xpju9/)

Comment: i want when i click outside then that div will close so how to do with javascript

Answer (score 0):

You can use hasClass property which is not prefable nowadays

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
      $(".theme-button").click(function(){ 
        if($( ".theme-colors" ).hasClass( "shown" )){
           $(".theme-colors").removeClass("shown");
        }
        else{
            $(".theme-colors").addClass("shown");
        }

      });
    });
```

better solution is  toggleClass property which is already do this control and do it

```
$(document).ready(function(){
          $(".theme-button").click(function(){                  
              $(".theme-colors").toggleClass("shown");
          });
 });
```

Comment: There is a jQuery function for that: toggleClass

Answer (score 0):

Here you go with a solution [jsfiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/n68t3bc4/)

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".theme-button").click(function(){
    if ($(".theme-colors").hasClass("shown")) {
      $(".theme-colors").removeClass("shown");
    } else {
      $(".theme-colors").addClass("shown");
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.theme-colors.shown {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.theme-colors {
    width: 280px;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1030;
    top: 50%;
    right: 0;
    background: #fff;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 15px rgba(0,0,0,.04), 0 1px 6px rgba(0,0,0,.04);
    box-shadow: 0 1px 15px rgba(0,0,0,.04), 0 1px 6px rgba(0,0,0,.04);
    -webkit-transform: translate(280px,-50%);
    transform: translate(280px,-50%);
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform .4s ease-out;
    transition: -webkit-transform .4s ease-out;
    transition: transform .4s ease-out;
    transition: transform .4s ease-out,-webkit-transform .4s ease-out;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}

body {
    font-family: Nunito,sans-serif;
    font-size: .8rem;
    font-weight: 400;
    color: #303030;
    background: #f8f8f8;
}

.p-4 {
    padding: 1.5rem!important;
}

.text-muted {
    color: #909090!important;
}
.mb-2, .my-2 {
    margin-bottom: .5rem!important;
}
p {
    font-size: .85rem;
    line-height: 1.3rem;
    font-family: Nunito,sans-serif;
}
.justify-content-between {
    -webkit-box-pack: justify!important;
    -ms-flex-pack: justify!important;
    justify-content: space-between!important;
}
.d-flex {
    display: -webkit-box!important;
    display: -ms-flexbox!important;
    display: flex!important;
}
.theme-colors .theme-color-purple {
    border: 3px solid #922c88;
    background: #922c88;
}
.theme-colors .theme-color {
    width: 24px;
    height: 24px;
    display: inline-block;
    border-radius: 20px;
    -webkit-transition: background .25s;
    transition: background .25s;
}
a {
    color: #303030;
    -webkit-transition: color .2s;
    transition: color .2s;
}
.theme-colors .theme-color-blue {
    border: 3px solid #145388;
    background: #145388;
}
.theme-colors .theme-color-green {
    border: 3px solid #576a3d;
    background: #576a3d;
}
.theme-colors .theme-color-orange {
    border: 3px solid #e2863b;
    background: #e2863b;
}
.theme-colors .theme-color-red {
    border: 3px solid #880a1f;
    background: #880a1f;
}


.pl-4, .px-4 {
    padding-left: 1.5rem!important;
}

.theme-colors .theme-button {
    position: absolute;
    left: -34px;
    background: #fff;
    padding: 13px 7px 13px 7px;
    border-radius: .2rem;
    color: #303030;
    -webkit-box-shadow: -2px 0 5px rgba(0,0,0,.04);
    box-shadow: -2px 0 5px rgba(0,0,0,.04);
    font-size: 20px;
    top: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    color: #922c88;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="toggleshown" class="theme-colors"><div class="p-4"><p class="text-muted mb-2">Light Theme</p> <div class="d-flex flex-row justify-content-between mb-4"><a href="#" class="theme-color theme-color-purple active"></a><a href="#" class="theme-color theme-color-blue"></a><a href="#" class="theme-color theme-color-green"></a><a href="#" class="theme-color theme-color-orange"></a><a href="#" class="theme-color theme-color-red"></a></div> <p class="text-muted mb-2">Dark Theme</p> <div class="d-flex flex-row justify-content-between"><a href="#" class="theme-color theme-color-purple"></a><a href="#" class="theme-color theme-color-blue"></a><a href="#" class="theme-color theme-color-green"></a><a href="#" class="theme-color theme-color-orange"></a><a href="#" class="theme-color theme-color-red"></a></div></div> <div class="pb-0 pl-4 pt-4"><fieldset class="form-group" id="__BVID__10"><legend tabindex="-1" class="col-form-label pt-0" id="__BVID__10__BV_label_">Border Radius</legend><div tabindex="-1" role="group"><div role="radiogroup" tabindex="-1" class="" id="__BVID__11"><div class="custom-control custom-control-inline custom-radio"><input type="radio" name="radius" autocomplete="off" class="custom-control-input" value="rounded" id="__BVID__12"><label class="custom-control-label" for="__BVID__12">Rounded</label></div> <div class="custom-control custom-control-inline custom-radio"><input type="radio" name="radius" autocomplete="off" class="custom-control-input" value="flat" id="__BVID__13"><label class="custom-control-label" for="__BVID__13">Flat</label></div></div><!----><!----><!----></div></fieldset></div> <a href="#" class="theme-button"><i class="fa fa-cogs"></i></a></div>
```

Use of `.hasClass` property

reference [hasClass Documentation](https://api.jquery.com/hasClass/)

Here you go with pure JavaScript [solution](https://jsfiddle.net/1kxfmv5q/)

Comment: There is a jQuery function for that: toggleClass

Comment: how to do with javascript

Comment: @DeveloperLion didn't get your question

Comment: @DeveloperLion here you go with pure javascript https://jsfiddle.net/1kxfmv5q/

Comment: @shiladitya ty for your comment this is working fine but i need one more requirement that requirement that is when i click outside then close that slide

Comment: @DeveloperLion Use document.body.click to track outside click.

Comment: I tried lot but not closing in a proper way plz give me solution with javascript